# Formula for unique distribution of colored balls into boxes

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, balls-in-bins

I'm trying to figure out how to uniquely distribute 2 red balls and 2 blue balls into 3 indistinguishable boxes.

My mind leapt to the general case, and I've found that there is a bijection between the number of ways we can uniquely distribute $k_1$ [color-one] balls, $k_2$ [color-two] balls, $k_3$ [color-three] balls, ... $k_f$ [color-$f$] balls into $n$ boxes and the number of ways to factor a product of primes into $n$ distinct factors.

More clearly, let $p_i$ give the $i$th prime. Then I'm looking for the number of ways to factor $$\prod_{i=1}^f p_i^{k_i}$$ into $n$ distinct factors. Call this number $\Phi$.

How can I approach this?

**Edit:** A bit more research revealed the following:

Let $\eta(k_1,k_2,...,k_f) = \prod_{i=1}^f p_i^{k_i}$. Also, let $Q(x)$ give the number of multiplicative partitions of a non-squarefree number $x$. Then we have

$$\Phi=\mu^2(\eta)\cdot B(f) + (1-\mu^2(\eta))\cdot Q(\eta)$$ where $\mu(n)$ denotes  the Möbius function and $B(f)=\sum_{k=0}^n  S(n,k) $ is the $f$th Bell number.

Now I just need to find a formula for $Q(x)$; could someone help me in this regard?

Comment: Not sure the analogy is helpful.  The different colored balls (or different primes) are effectively independent of each other.  There are $\binom {n+k_i-1}{k_i}$ ways to place the $i^{th}$ balls...just multiply those.

Comment: Note:  I am assuming that order matters...is that what you intended?  That is, for your first example, I am assuming that $(RR),(BB),\emptyset$ is different from $(BB),(RR),\emptyset$.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: @lulu Order does not matter. That is, the two distributions you describe are equivalent. Why does the approach you mentioned require that order matters?

Comment: Ah.  That is harder, as the symmetries of the various expression are not the same.

Comment: You should edit your question to specify that the boxes are indistinguishable.

Comment: @lulu I've edited it to reflect this point. What do you mean by the "symmetries of the various expressions are not the same?" Also, does the fact that order does not matter mean that the analogy is incorrect?

Comment: No, the same issue arises in both descriptions.  Is $24=2\times 2\times 6$ different from $24=12\times 2\times 2$, say.  My method (Stars and Bars) retains order.  That simplifies things a lot.  To see the problem, note that my factoring of $24$ is equivalent to exactly $3$ factorings...according to where the $6$ is placed.  But the factoring $24=1\times 3\times 8$ is equivalent to $6$ factorings.  And the factoring $2\times 2\times 2$ is equivalent only to itself.

Comment: (typo in my last comment:  I meant $24=6\times 2\times 2$ of course).

Comment: As André Nicolas points out in this answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185990/find-all-ways-to-factor-a-number), this is an insanely hard problem. If you came up with a formula for this, you'd have as just a special case with one colour, where $n=p^k$, a formula for the number of partitions of $k$. This alone is a hugely challenging and well studied problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory).

That said, your question alone is a nice proof of a connection between seemingly disparate things!

Comment: @lulu Forgive the necromancy, but where did you get $\binom{n+k_i-1}{k_i}$ from? Using stars and bars suggests that  $\binom{n+k_i-1}{k_i - 1}$ would be the number of ways to place the $i$th balls, but experimentally, I can see that this is not the case...

Comment: @TiwaAina   It's just straight [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).   Note that the variables here are the opposite of the ones used in the wiki article (i.e., $k's$ and $n's$ are reversed).  Here we are looking to count $n-$tuples of non-negative numbers that add to $k_i$.